# How to get the list of all project packages and sub packages in Java?

Tags: java, package

How do I list the sub packages of a package in my Java project.

For example:

```
org.example.test
org.example.test.test1
org.example.test.test2
org.example.another_test
```

How to list all the packages belonging to the project, which starts with `org.example`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the list of packages in a java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500004/getting-the-list-of-packages-in-a-java-project)

Comment: See if the link below provides a satisfying answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893174/list-all-subpackages-of-a-package